# How to show current weather condition of current location in android?

Tags: android, weather-api

Can any one tell me how to show current weather condition of a current location in android.
Is there any examples available to achieve this?

Suggestion please.

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. Use Google instead: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=android+weather+webservice

Comment: use yahoo weather api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Free Local Weather REST API](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/location-search-api.aspx). In the api, there is a provision to get weather of location in longitude/latitude. Return types are in JSON, XML etc

Comment: if you find it useful, click the tick AND press the triangle ;)